# Parse directory listing and pass to another script?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a PowerShell script that will loop through a directory in `C:\` drive and parse the filenames with the file extension to another script to use.

Basically, the output of the directory listing should be accessible to be parsed to another script one by one. The script is a compiling script which expects an argument (parameter) to be parsed to it in order to compile the specific module (filename).

**Code:**

```
Clear-Host $Path = "C:\SandBox\" 
Get-ChildItem $Path -recurse -force | ForEach { If ($_.extension -eq ".cob") 
    { 
        Write-Host $_.fullname 
    } 
} 
If ($_.extension -eq ".pco") 
{ 
    Write-Host $_.fullname } 
}
```

Comment: So far what have you tried ?

Comment: Hi There... I found some code on the net that looks like doing what i am asking but it does not correlate to me really.

Comment: I found this piece of logic:

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to parse the output as text, that's deprecated.

Here's something that might work for you:

```
# getmyfiles.ps1

Param( [string])$Path = Get-Location )

dir $Path -Recurse -Force | where { 
    $_.Extension -in @('.cob', '.pco')
}

# this is another script that calls the above

. getmyfile.ps1 -Path c:\sandbox | foreach-object {
    # $_ is a file object. I'm just printing its full path but u can do other stuff eith it 
    Write-host $_.Fullname
}
```

Comment: This is not working. Gives me an error: Parameter declarations are a comma-separated list of variable names with optional initializer expressions.
At line:1 char:16

Answer (score -1):

```
Clear-Host
$Path = "C:\Sandbox\"  
$Items = Get-ChildItem $Path -recurse -Include "*.cob", "*.pco"
```

From your garbled code am guessing you want to return a list of files that have .cob and .pco file extensions. You could use the above code to gather those.

```
$File = $Items.name 
$FullName = $items.fullname
Write-Host $Items.name 
$File
$FullName
```

Adding the above lines will allow you to display them in various ways. You can pick the one that suites your needs then loop through them on a for-each.

As a rule its not a place for code to be writen for you, but you have tried to add some to the questions so I've taken a look. Sometimes you just want a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Hi Guys. Thanks for the feedback. I tried this in powershell terminal but it for some or other reason does not work and output $Items.name neither $Items.fullname instead, it does output $Items (with the full pat) which is not actually what I want. Any help please.